# Please emphasize that web browser questions are off-topic

Tags: feature-request, scope, help-center, tour

There seems to be an increase in questions about web browsers and extensions/add-ons.

Can we get some tweaks to the custom off-topic area in the Help Center? To wit, on the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page, we have:

> ### What about other Web Application related questions?
>
> #### Please note that the following subjects are considered off-topic here:
>
> - Desktop software
> - Applications for mobile devices such as the Android or iPad
> - Hosted scripts such as Wordpress.org and phpBB
> - Web applications containing adult content
> - Developing & programming web applications
> - Browsers and their features
> - App recommendations unless prior research is shown

Can we have "Browsers and their features" moved to the top of the list? As well, could we strengthen the language? I suggest:

- **Web browsers**, including features and browser extensions/add-ons

Comment: I agree.  We can take a look at it.  My take on [this MSO post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215054/make-migration-paths-just-another-off-topic-reason) is that there are going to be some changes to the system rolled out, so it will be a good time to assess our options in this department anyway.

Comment: @jonsca: That post is just a modest proposal and is no wise imminent.

Comment: I read "custom off-topic" and my brain went to the closing dialog, that was why I had included that link.  I agree that it may not happen any time soon, anyway.  I am looking at the help center topic you linked to and what is displayed on the "tour" page and those lists are out of sync.  I'll get with the other mods and see if we can line everything up and bump up the web browser line.

Comment: Nothing should be out of sync. I copy-pasted from that page.

Comment: The page you linked to is out of sync with what's listed on http://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour (which includes Trello feature requests, etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have updated the Help Center page to reflect your change, added your change to the Tour, moved "creating or developing a web application" higher on the list, and added that to the Tour as well.