# Are questions about plugins on- or off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

The question [Does the ChatGPT Image Editor plugin do cut-and-paste?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/173540/18147) was kept closed under the reason:

> This is a question about a plugin for ChatGPT. [Blindspots](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/197518/blindspots)**♦** [Jan 18 at 4:15](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/173540/does-the-chatgpt-image-editor-plugin-do-cut-and-paste#comment164737_173540)

However, I see questions about plugins that are open, e.g.:

1. [How to enable Bountysource plugin on GitHub to have integration with issues?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/84152/18147)
2. ["Image too big" in draw.io stored on Google Drive using the diagrams.net plugin](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/150766/18147)
3. [How to remove comment feed from Disqus comment plugin?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/42890/18147)

Are questions about plugins on- or off-topic?

Plug-in= component that adds a specific feature to an existing application. The plugins are installed either via the website or via the browser.

Assume the question is not a software recommendation. @Laurel Some browser extensions such as the Reddit Enhancement Suite may change the site behavior/UI. Questions about the site behavior/UI given a browser extension don't seem to be addressed by the [existing discussion](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2575/197614).

Comment: I feel like that #0 might be off topic here because it might be about prompt engineering (similar to "Can ChatGPT write non-rhyming poetry?"). For all these questions, it would be helpful to know what *plugin* means (eg, is it a browser extension?)

Comment: @Laurel plug-in= component that adds a specific feature to an existing application. Aka add-on. Regarding that specific question, it's not about prompt engineering but about which operations that plugin can perform.

Comment: No, what I'm asking is how these plugins are installed.

Comment: @Laurel Either via the website or the browser.

Comment: We have an [existing discussion](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2575/197614) from the dawn of time about browser extensions (which seems to be half of what this question is about). Do you think that this should be changed? (Anything that's "installed" on the webapp side of things is quite a different beast, imo.)

Comment: @Laurel Some browser extensions such as the Reddit Enhancement Suite may change the site behavior/UI. Questions about the site behavior/UI given a browser extension don't seem to be addressed by the [existing discussion](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2575/197614).

Comment: Another plugin: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/129211/how-do-i-install-spreadsheet-freezer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are questions about browsers/plug-ins/add-ons appropriate?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61/are-questions-about-browsers-plug-ins-add-ons-appropriate)

Comment: @TheMaster I think it would be valuable to keep this discussion open since the other one was 10+ years ago with people who no longer use the site. Because Meta. (We could close the other one as a duplicate of this one, but that's probably overkill.)

Comment: @Laurel I don't think there's any new factors that need discussing and Jeff's answer hits the spot, compared to my word salad answer. Wisdom of the ancestors is superior to ours. But, if there are factors that we haven't yet considered, I think we should keep it open. If there isn't any, after a sufficient period, I think we can close. OTOH, if Franck edits this post to mean a specific question and not a general idea, I believe my answer is more appropriate and this post shouldn't be closed. (I'm not retracting my close vote though because I can't cast it later).

Comment: @TheMaster even if jeff's answer hits the spot, there's no reason not to reaffirm that the conclusion is the same 10 years later. It's not like this meta is overwhelmed with things to discuss.

Comment: @user400654 Why not reaffirm in the original thread? Upvote,  or add a new answer there? I feel there's nothing more to add to this. If we were to reach a different conclusion, yes maybe. But it seems we're just reinventing the wheel here...

Comment: @TheMaster I'm ok either way. Thanks for finding the duplicate / great reference!

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Thanks. I believe this answer still has value, if we ever to focus of the specifics of the question rather on the general policy.  I'm ok either way too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Help/on-topic](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says

> If your question generally covers …

> - Using Gmail, Facebook, Twitter, Google, or any other website which behaves like an application
> - **Features of browsers which are directly related to the use of a web application (Greasemonkey scripts for a web application, etc.)**

Highlighting the second point, even if the usage requires scripting, as long as it is related to a web application, it is on-topic here. Greasemonkey scripts are given as an example. Notwithstanding the fact [browsers and their extensions are offtopic](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2575/please-emphasize-that-web-browser-questions-are-off-topic), if a script directly relates to usage of web application, they are considered on topic. These scripts are essentially browser extensions, but they're explicitly quoted as on-topic.

Regardless, chatGPT plugin is not a **browser** extension at all. It is a cloud to cloud plugin as written in the [docs](https://platform.openai.com/docs/plugins/introduction). Therefore, the question of topicality of browser extensions doesn't arise at all. A similar example would be Google apps script. They're [explicitly on topic, if they directly relate to usage of web application(eg:Google sheets), even if they're code](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2446/should-questions-about-google-apps-scripts-be-allowed-on-webapps).  Even Google sheets formulas are code and they're ontopic, because it directly relates to the usage of web application Google sheets. Here, it is not even about coding, but about usage and therefore it is more on-topic than those questions.

Voted to reopen.

#### Related:

- [Jeff Atwood's answer on Plugins](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/62/)

> > is the primary focus of the question the website?

> In other words, I think it's OK, if the question can be read

> > I need my browser to do this so it works better with {specific website}

- [A Moderator's criteria](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4746/) on plug ins.

Comment: Completely agree about server side "plugins". Not really sure what you mean by "if a script directly relates to usage of web application…" since essentially all browser plugins/extensions/scripts can be used with a web application (or website). What plugin/extension/browser-script questions are considered off-topic then?

Comment: @Laurel I believe the prevalent school of thought is "websites" are not equal to "web applications". As long as the scope of question is about using the extension in a web application - such as chatGPT, Google sheets, I believe it should be on-topic. For eg, Cookie deletion extension outside of a web application, but in general, would be off-topic(for eg in the context of webapps.stackexchange.com/q/173727 ). But there are general extensions too - say Proxy/VPN extension(which makes the browser access through a proxy), browser theme extension, universal ad blocker extension, password managers

Comment: @Laurel Also when this proposal was raised https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2575/ I believe they specifically meant  and I quote **"Browsers and their features" Web browsers, including features and browser extensions/add-ons**, which would mean specifically mean **things related to the browser** like how to install/uninstall a addon in a browser  or asking for a add-on recommendation or an add-on to manipulate browser settings - isolation modes,  proxies and stuff.. and not about a webapp or a website in general.

Comment: @Laurel Jeff Atwood's quote summarises my thoughts on this perfectly: [**is the primary focus of the question the website?**](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/62/), then it's ok.